# using AssertJ for comparing 2 csv's in Java

Tags: java, assertj

I have this method in Java where I am trying to compare 2 csv's file using assertJ and the method is as follows. I am using the ignorefields with Regex function as seen below. The Regex is for ignoring the values for coulmns which has timestamp in them. I see that those columns are still being compared and the assertion fails. Can anyone please let me know what is that I am doing wrong here?

public class RCSV {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    try {
    CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file1.csv"));
        List<String[]> Entries1 = reader1.readAll();
        System.out.println(Entries1);
    CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file2.csv"));
        List<String[]> Entries2 = reader2.readAll();
        
        assertThat(Entries1).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes("[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")
        .isEqualTo(Entries2);
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     
}
```

}

This is the error  that I see in the console:
java.lang.AssertionError:
when recursively comparing field by field, but found the following difference:

Top level actual and expected objects differ:

- actual value   : "2020-11-04 13:31:51"
- expected value : "2020-11-05 13:31:52"

Answer (score 0):

[`ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.18.0/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(java.lang.String...)) ignores fields whose **name** match the regex, it's not evaluated against fields value.

I think a better approach would be to filter out the timestamp from what CSVReader reads if that's possible and use simple list assertion like: `assertThat(entries1).isEqualTo(entries2)`

If you can't do that, try to define an element comparator for the `String[]` that would ignore elements at indexes corresponding to timestamp and then use this assertion:

```java
assertThat(entries1).usingElementComparator​(comparatorIgnoringTimestamp) 
                    .isEqualTo(entries2)
```